# Does Scout have inbuilt mixins like Compass?

Tags: css, frontend, compass-sass, scout-sass

I'm doing some front-end work using [Scout](http://mhs.github.com/scout-app/).

I know [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) has some inbuilt mixins that we could import, such as:

```
@import "compass/css3/font-face";
@include font-face(
   'FontAwesome',
    font-files(
       "#{$fontAwesomePath}.woff", woff,
       "#{$fontAwesomePath}.ttf", truetype,
       "#{$fontAwesomePath}.svg#FontAwesomeRegular", svg),
       '#{$fontAwesomePath}.eot',
    normal,
    normal);
```

How about [Scout](http://mhs.github.com/scout-app/)? There are many snippets using these @import functions and I'm not sure if [Scout](http://mhs.github.com/scout-app/) already has them or should I write them on my own?

Answer (score 0):

As of today, Scout [gives access](https://github.com/mhs/scout-app/blob/master/src/config/Gemfile) to 4 libraries:

- [compass-960-plugin](http://github.com/chriseppstein/compass-960-plugin)
- [yui-compass-plugin](http://github.com/chriseppstein/yui-compass-plugin)
- [compass-h5bp](http://rubygems.org/gems/compass-h5bp)
- [zen-grids](http://zengrids.com/)

Note: Scout is a GUI for Sass & Compass and it can not be compared to a Sass framework like [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) or [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/).

Comment: Alright, but simple question - how to use these compass mixins in Scout then? Because something like `@include border-radius(4px, 4px);` outputs `Syntax error: Undefinied mixin 'border-radius'.`?

Comment: Have you previously loaded the mixin, using one of the following commands? `@import "compass/css3/border-radius"` or `@import "compass/css3"`